# ID3D11XEffectMatrixVariable replace with what?

Tags: c, visual-c++, directx-11

i'm making a directx engine but i'm stuck with this one little problem.
I want to not use fx files but shader files, but my question is with what can i replace the `ID3D11XEffectMatrixVariable`?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think your question would be better if was in this place [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) to manage your shader metadata and constants, you take over responsibility for binding and updating constant buffers directly.

For example, in the Direct3D Tutorial ([Win32 desktop](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) or [Windows Store](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct3D-Tutorial-Sample-08667fb0)) the HLSL shader defines which constant buffer has the matrices:

```
cbuffer cbNeverChanges : register( b0 )
{
    matrix View;
};
```

and you manually set this up and bind it in your C++ code to render with it:

Types:

```
struct CBNeverChanges
{
    XMMATRIX mView;
};

ID3D11Buffer* g_pCBNeverChanges = nullptr;
```

Setup:

```
// Create the constant buffers
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(CBNeverChanges);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, nullptr, &g_pCBNeverChanges );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;
```

Update:

```
CBNeverChanges cbNeverChanges;
cbNeverChanges.mView = XMMatrixTranspose( g_View );
g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( g_pCBNeverChanges, 0, nullptr, &cbNeverChanges, 0, 0 );
```

Render:

```
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pCBNeverChanges );
```

Note the `XMMatrixTranspose` is because HLSL defaults to using 'column-major' matrices while DirectX programs typically use 'row-major' matrices.

Comment: Thank you Chuck, i fully understand my problem now and i understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best and easiest path forward is as described in Chuck's answer.

However, if you are looking to dynamically access a shader constant by name like in the Effects framework, then you have a lot of work ahead.

You will need to learn about [Shader Reflection](http://members.gamedev.net/JasonZ/Heiroglyph/D3D11ShaderReflection.pdf) using [D3D11Reflect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728670(v=vs.85).aspx).

This will allow you to inspect the shader code to find information on all constants including their names, constant buffer, offset in the constant buffer, and constant buffer register. Using the information you've gathered from reflection, you can dynamically create your buffers and map the name of each constant to where it resides in memory.

Then when you update the values on the CPU, you will need to update the constant buffer on the GPU.

Also see the answer regarding D3D11 reflection [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62361/working-with-d3d11-opengl-shader-reflection) for an example of how to iterate over each variable in each constant buffer.

Comment: A question, does this also teach you how to work with light? I'm a little bit further now and i'm trying to give my program some light. PS. If it doesn't could you tell me how if there is something on this?